# Symfony - Simulate login and security context in console command

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently coding a custom console command on Symfony (2+).

My command call one service that use the security context with dependency injection (check role).

In order to keep that security check in my service, i  would like to create a specific user and log this user in my console command.

How can i simulate that login and have a usable security context in my command ?

My service check :

```
if ($this->securityContext->getToken() == null ||
    !$this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
)
```

My command is a classic console command that extends *ContainerAwareCommand*

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the previous answer, this is the right way for Symfony 5.

```php
class LoginProvider
{
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function login(User $user): void
    {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            $user->getEmail(),   // Your $credentials
            'main',
            $user->getRoles()    // Don't forget
        );

        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    }

    public function logout(): void
    {
        $this->tokenStorage->setToken(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

You can programatically authenticate a user in Symfony2 like this:

```
// create the authentication token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $user,
    null,
    'main',
    $user->getRoles());
// give it to the security context
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

EDIT based on comment:

- Security context is deprecated as of Symfony 2.6. Use this instead:

`$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($t‌​oken);`

thanks @andrea-sprega

Comment: Security context is deprecated as of Symfony 2.6. Use this instead:

`$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);`

Comment: You can also do this: `$token = new AnonymousToken('dummy', 'dummy', ['ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR']);`

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated in Symfony 5 as security.context doesn't exist anymore.

And Security doesn't have a setToken() (only get).

So we have to use this service:

```
use App\Security\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class LoginProvider
{

    /** @var TokenStorageInterface */
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function login(): void
    {
        $user = new User($this->getToken());

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            $this->getToken(),
            'main'
        );

        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    }

    private function getToken(): string
    {
        // HTTP call with login and password
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? you don't define a `this->getToken()` method, and `$user` is undefined

Comment: Sorry, I'm just completed this, but it was a part specific to my app.